# R bars on histograms

Tags: r, plot

I have my code to draw histograms with bars and to same degree it work:

```
V_max=10
V_min=0
H=1
n=1

x_lim_min=-1
x_lim_max=13


C=c(0,0.01,0.1,1)


par(mfrow=c(length(C)+1,1), mar = c(2,0,2,0),oma = c(1,5,0,0))


V <- function( C, H, n ){
  1 / (1 + (C / H)^n) 
}


base_plot_fun <- function(x, x1, y, y1) {
  mean_x <- mean(x)
  mean_x1 <- mean(x1)
  
  # initialize the plot
  plot(
    0,
    0,
    ylim = range(c(y$counts, y1$counts)),
    xlim = range(c(y$breaks, y1$breaks)),
    xlab = "x",
    ylab = "counts",
    type = "n"
  )
  
  
  corners <- par('usr') # get the corners of the plots
  
  x_left <- corners[1]
  x_right <- quantile(x, 0.95) # at 95 percentile, change as needed
  
  x1_left <- x_right
  x1_right <- quantile(x1, 0.05) # at 5th percentile, change if needed
  
  rect(
    xleft = x_left,
    xright = x_right,
    ybottom = corners[3],
    ytop = corners[4],
    col = 'lightblue',
    density = 100
  )
  rect(
    xleft = x1_left,
    xright = x1_right,
    ybottom = corners[3],
    ytop = corners[4],
    col = 'pink',
    density = 100
  )
}



x <- rnorm(100,V_min,1)
x1 <- rnorm(100,V_max,1)
y <- hist(x,plot=FALSE,breaks = 20)
y1 <- hist(x1, plot=FALSE,breaks=20)

base_plot_fun(x = x, x1 = x1, y = y, y1 = y1)
plot(y, col='gray48',add=T,xlim=c(x_lim_min,x_lim_max))
plot(y1, col='gray48',add=T,xlim=c(x_lim_min,x_lim_max))


mylist <- list()
for(i in 1:length(C)){
  V_C <- V_max*V(C[i],H,n)
  x3 <- rnorm(100,V_C,1)
  mylist[i] <- mean(x3)
  y3 <- hist(x3, plot=FALSE,breaks=20)
  
  plot(y3, col='gray48',xlim=c(x_lim_min,x_lim_max))
}



abline(v=mean_x3,col='forestgreen',lwd=3)


# histograms, not plotted
y <- hist(x,plot=FALSE,breaks = 20)
y1 <- hist(x1, plot=FALSE,breaks=20)


base_plot_fun(x = x, x1 = x1, y = y, y1 = y1)

corners <- par('usr') # get the corners of the plots

mean_x <- mean(x)
mean_x1 <- mean(x1)

x_left <- corners[1]
x_right <- quantile(x, 0.95) # at 95 percentile, change as needed

x1_left <- x_right
x1_right <- quantile(x1, 0.05) # at 5th percentile, change if needed

plot(y, col='lightgray',add=TRUE)
plot(y1, col='gray48',add=TRUE)


abline(v=mean_x,col='forestgreen',lwd=3)
abline(v=mean_x1,col='forestgreen',lwd=3)


abline(v=x_right,col='steelblue',lwd=3)
abline(v=x1_right,col='firebrick',lwd=3)
```

I have problems with this code. It don't show means as green bars on histograms and blue

```
x_right <- quantile(x, 0.95)
```

and red

```
x1_right <- quantile(x1, 0.05)
```

as bars on histogram. I do not know how to fix my code Therefore, I am asking for help from more experienced people from the forum.

I want that my histograms have the same bars as in add picture for my histograms[image: plot]

Comment: Can you clarify your question and include a picture of your expected plot?

Comment: I hope it clarify question

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure what your problem is, but in a tidyverse and ggplot environment I would try this

```
library(tidyverse)
data.frame(x, x1) %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(value)) + 
   geom_histogram() + 
   geom_vline(data = . %>%  group_by(name) %>% 
                summarise(mean = mean(value, na.rm =T),
                          q95 = quantile(value, probs = 0.95),
                          q05 = quantile(value, probs = 0.05)) %>% 
                pivot_longer(-1, names_to = "type"), aes(xintercept = value, color = type), size= 1.4) + 
   facet_wrap(~name, ncol = 1)
```

[image]

and by replacing the geom_vline with following lines all plots show the bars of the total data (here: x & x1):

```
geom_vline(data = . %>%  
                mutate(mean = mean(value, na.rm =T),
                          q95 = quantile(value, probs = 0.95),
                          q05 = quantile(value, probs = 0.05)) %>% 
                distinct(name, mean, q95, q05) %>% 
                pivot_longer(-1, names_to = "type"), aes(xintercept = value, color = type), size= 1.4)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I really mean that my 2 top charts should have a layout like the one in the picture, i.e. beyond the mean, one bar each.And charts below as in the picture mean bars. Sorry if I didn't ask you precisely enough. Can I help with that?

Comment: Please. Could you help me with that?

Comment: I have no idea what you want. Sorry.